# how to set text on button which is selected from menu in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I make a menu option which is show on button click .I need to show deleted option on button text.by default "select value" text display.Now if user select any other value it should show on button.
can you please tell me how it is possible ?
Plunker:http://plnkr.co/edit/Fxb3H4mhKXdcdb4zR93h?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.x" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@0.10.0" data-semver="0.10.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="DropdownCtrl">
  <div class="btn-group"  >
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" >
        Select value <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li ng-repeat="choice in items">
          <a href>{{choice}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>

    </body>
<script>
  angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
function DropdownCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    'The first choice!',
    'And another choice for you.',
    'but wait! A third!'
  ];

  $scope.status = {
    isopen: true
  };


}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `$scope` variable to keep track of the button text. Instead of making the button text a string ('Select value'), make it a `$scope` variable with a default value of 'Select value'. Make the dropdown links call a function that updates that `$scope` variable.

See: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AZum0agwTqgUJuQjTbvx?p=preview)